# How to get a specific kernel version for Raspberry Pi Linux?

Tags: kernel

I'm trying to find the source for version 3.12.20, but the current 3.12.y version on [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) is 3.12.24. I understand I can just update my current version, but shouldn't downloading the source for my current version surely be faster?

Comment: Look at the related questions to the right of this page.  Does one help answer your question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do:
`sudo rpi-update hash`
with the hash being the kernel version from here: https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-firmware

For example:
`sudo rpi-update ba43047bec24d5f0a4150f09a37884240f8926d2` would install `3.12.35`

Comment: Unfortunatelly you will have problems with installing specific for this version headers-files. [Rpi-Source](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/rpi-source) can save you day in some situations.

Comment: Here is a more comprehensive tutorial explaining where to look up the hash and how it works. https://retropie.org.uk/forum/topic/31045/how-to-change-to-a-different-firmware-and-kernel-combo

Answer (score 2):

Try `sudo apt-get install linux-image-### linux-image-extra-###`

Where `###` is the version number (eg. 3.11.0-15-generic)

You can check your kernel version with `uname -r`

Comment: This is the *generic* Debian/Ubuntu way of doing it, yet not for the Raspberry Pi. The above answer (`rpi-update`) is correct as the kernel images are not installed via `apt-get` under Raspbian.